# Can I use the word "data" without an article in the sentence?

Tags: articles, zero-article

The sentence goes "At the same time, data shows that…"

Can I use the word "data" without an article in the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use data without an article. It is actually a plural noun of the much less commonly used word [datum](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/datum) so normal rules for plurals apply to it. The reason you can use a definite article with data sometimes is because you can use "the" to refer to groups of nouns if you want to refer to a specific group in particular, so in this case, a specific grouping of data, rather than all or any data. [This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10854/rule-on-absence-of-the-article-the-with-plural-nouns) on the English stack exchange explains it succinctly.